# Display tags that only appear in one category

Tags: functions, wp-query, tags

I'm trying to get this less manual than it currently is. I want to display tags that appear in only a single category, so if they are in a post that has two categories, I want that tag ignored.

The following code works, but is a little clunky. Ideally I'd like to be able to skip having to add the excludes and just have it figure it out itself.

```
<?php 
function pl8_artist_list($catname, $exclude) {
    $custom_query = new WP_Query('posts_per_page=-1&category_name='.$catname.'&cat='.$exclude.'');
    if ($custom_query->have_posts()) :
        while ($custom_query->have_posts()) : $custom_query->the_post();
            $posttags = get_the_tags();
            if ($posttags) {
                foreach($posttags as $tag) {
                    echo '<h2>' . $tag->name . '</h2>';
                    echo '<p>' . $tag->description . '</p>';
                    echo '<p><a href="http://beatexplorers.com/artist/'. $tag->slug . '">Read posts about ' . $tag->name . '</a></p>';
                }
            }
        endwhile;
    wp_reset_postdata(); // reset the query
    endif;
} 
?>
```

And I call it like so:

```
<?php
pl8_artist_list(trance, -3,-11,-4,-8);
?>
```

The excludes being the other categories that the tags may appear in.

I'm quite new to PHP, so any light that could be shed would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This loop starts by fetching all posts in given category. then goes through each tag of current post, fetches the posts for each tag, and if all of the posts have 0 or 1 category, prints that category. So, if you have lots of tags, lots of posts, this could be slow-ish.

```
function wa_60126_pl8_artist_list($catname) {

  //this part fetches the posts in the category provided
  $custom_query = new WP_Query('posts_per_page=-1&category_name='.$catname );
  if ($custom_query->have_posts()) :
      while ($custom_query->have_posts()) : $custom_query->the_post();


  $posttags = get_the_tags();

  // build the tag list
  if ($posttags) {
      foreach($posttags as $posttag) {

          // fetch the posts with same tags
          $posts_same_tag = get_posts( array ( 'tag' => $posttag->name ) );
          $is_safetag = TRUE;
          // check if has only one category
          foreach( $posts_same_tag as $st_post ) {
          // if it has more than one category, this tag is no good
              if ( count ( wp_get_post_categories($st_post->ID)) > 1 ){
                  $is_safetag = FALSE; break;
              }
          }
          // end of posts and its dirty?
          if($is_safetag) $safetags[] = $posttag;
      }
  }
  endwhile;
  wp_reset_postdata(); // reset the query
  endif;
  // now lets echo the safetags
  foreach( $safetags as $tag) {
        echo '<h2>' . $tag->name . '</h2>';
        echo '<p>' . $tag->description . '</p>';
        echo '<p><a href="http://beatexplorers.com/artist/'. $tag->slug . '">Read posts about ' . $tag->name . '</a></p>';
  }

}
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that the code is being run on pages, so it doesn't have any categories assigned to it. I'd also like to avoid that because I don't want to have these list pages coming up in category pages.

Comment: no prob. i've updated my answer for that.

Comment: I was getting some syntax errors (and still am) trying to get this code to run.

It wouldn't execute at all, so i had to change `array ( 'tag' -> $posttag )` to `array( 'tag' => $posttag )` and am now getting a bunch of these:

`Warning: strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in /home/beatex/public_html/wp-includes/query.php on line 1787

Warning: preg_split() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given in /home/beatex/public_html/wp-includes/query.php on line 1788`

Any ideas?

Thanks for your help so far!

Comment: you're right! sorry bout that. the relevant change is `'tag' => $posttag->name`

Comment: Getting there... Errors have disappeared, but now it's just printing 'Read posts about' over and over. It's printed it ~130 times, which is weird because there's only 90 tags total on the whole site. Although maybe that's getting _all_ tags from all the posts in that category, which means there would be dupes.

You can take a look here if you need: http://beatexplorers.com/testpage

Comment: sorry if this is taking too long. i've tested the changes above and it should now print correcly!

Comment: Perfect, you're a legend. It's not urgent at all, more of just a learning exercise to see what other way there is to do it. Thanks so much for all your assistance.